# exceptions.badrequestkeyerror(key) when trying to get a value from request.form by key

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 forms on the same page. And to distinguish between them I use a hidden input like this:

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="formtype" value="logform">
    {{ loginForm.username() }}
    ...
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="formtype" value="regform">
    {{ registerForm.username() }}
    ...
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

After that I'm trying to check which form sends a POST request by getting a hidden input value:

```
loginForm = LoginForm()
registerForm = RegisterForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
  if request.form["formtype"] == "regform":
    print("registration!!!!!")
  elif request.form["formtype"] == "logform":
    print("login!!")
```

But I get an error that says:

```
if request.form["formtype"] == "regform":
raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand
KeyError: 'formtype'
```

The thing is that `request.form` is always empty.
What's wrong with the code? And how do I fix that?